# Form is not valid in django because it is empty

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to setup the register form for a website but it doesn't work because the form is empty so the print (request.POST) contains all the information but the form is not valid.

This is the view:

```
def register(request):
    print("Request submitted", request, request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print (request.POST)
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, prefix="user")
        print (form.is_valid())
        print (form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
        else:
            print("not valid")

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm(prefix="user")
    return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is the html:

```
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <h1>Alta de Usuario</h1>
        {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert">{{ message }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <form class="login-form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <label for="username">Nombre de usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Elige un nombre de usuario">
                <p class="form-valid"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">eMail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Introduce tu email">
                <p class="form-valid"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass">Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Introduce una contraseña">
                <p class="form-valid"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass">Repite contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Repite la contraseña introducida">
                <p class="form-valid"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></p>
            </div>
            <div class="disclaimer">
                <div class="check-terms">
                    <input class="terms" name="terms" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="terms">
                        Acepto los <a href="">términos y condiciones</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="access" type="submit">Registrarme</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

{#{{ form.as_p }}#}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: what in the `form.errors`?

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password1<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: What is the output of request.POST ?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['AgiMqNmx8RAgRVeABxGuZ4KO166RKS63T0kjXrFClIXAAacTlVLxSXVuMxfsTN6V'], 'username': ['alberto'], 'email': ['email@gmail.com'], 'pass': ['passwordddd', 'passwordddd']}>

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating the form like this instead:

`form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST, prefix="user")`

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)